# Calculating the sum of values from sibling elements using XSLT

Tags: loops, xslt, calculation

I am working on an automatic transform of measurements using XSLT. The transform of single measurements from one system (e.q. imperial) to another (e.g. metric) is working fine. But imperial measurements may take the form '5 ft 10 in' and I would want to convert this into a single metric value.

In my XML model for  I accommodate such combined measurements by allowing either a single value or multiple  child nodes. So when I find that my  has child nodes, I need to convert each one of those child elements to metric units and then add up the values to get one single metric result.

I am struggling to find the best way to process multiple child nodes and add up the resulting values. In an iterative language I would just process from the first to the next and update a global variable, but in XSLT I don't know if there is such a thing as a global variable that can be updated from subsequent calls to the same template.

Here is a (simplified) transform - this one handles only [ft_i] and [in_i] to m.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="measurement">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="measurement">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="normalise">
                    <xsl:with-param name="val" as="xs:double" select="number(text())"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="unitin" select="@ucum"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="normalise">
    <xsl:param name="val" as="xs:double"/>
    <xsl:param name="unitin"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$unitin eq '[ft_i]'">
            <xsl:attribute name="ucum">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="unit">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$val * 0.3048"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$unitin eq '[in_i]'">
            <xsl:attribute name="ucum">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="unit">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$val * 0.0254"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A simple test file:

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is 
        <measurement>
            <measurement unit="ft" 
                ucum=" [ft_i]">10</measurement>
            <measurement unit="in" 
                ucum="[in_i]">2</measurement>
        </measurement> 
        long
    </p>        
</topic>
```

The transform gives this:

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is 
        <measurement>
            <measurement ucum="m"
                unit="m">3.048</measurement>
            <measurement ucum="m" 
                unit="m">0.0508</measurement>
        </measurement> 
        long
    </p>        
</topic>
```

Obviously, I would want to see this:

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is 
        <measurement ucum="m" 
            unit="m">3.0988</measurement>
        long
    </p>        
</topic>
```

I could use an xsl:for-each on the child measurement nodes but how do I add the separate values to a global value which can then be output from the main template ?

Comment: Your problem is an example of the general problem of "getting the sum of computed values using XSLT". Searching for that will give you many answers to the problem, for example my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599323/xsl-sum-of-computed-amounts/39603188#39603188 Note that it's very easy in XSLT 2.0+, and quite difficult in XSLT 1.0, so you should make sure you are using XSLT 2.0+ if possible, and if that's not possible, you should state this as a constraint in the question.

Comment: Yes, in XSLT 2.0 it is easy and ellegant. One can even generalize the solution using an `xsl:function` to perform **any**, regardless ho complex, conversion logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that some values and attributes are constant the most simple approach would be using a complex XPath-2.0 expression. Then you can reduce your `measurement` template to:

```
<xsl:template match="measurement">
    <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">
        <xsl:copy-of select="sum(for $x in measurement return if (normalize-space($x/@ucum)= '[ft_i]') then xs:double(normalize-space($x))*0.3048 else xs:double(normalize-space($x))*0.0254)" />
    </measurement>
</xsl:template>
```

It assumes that the attributes stay the same and that there are only two units. But you could easily extend it.

---

Building templates based on your approach, the following solution is also possible:

```
<xsl:template match="measurement">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="summary">
            <xsl:for-each select="measurement">
                <val>
                    <xsl:call-template name="normalise">
                        <xsl:with-param name="val" as="xs:double" select="number(.)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="unitin" select="@ucum"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="count" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </val>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$summary/val[1]/@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="sum($summary/val)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="normalise">
    <xsl:param name="val" as="xs:double"/>
    <xsl:param name="unitin"/>
    <xsl:param name="count" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($unitin) = '[ft_i]'">
            <xsl:attribute name="ucum">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="unit">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$val * 0.3048"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="normalize-space($unitin) = '[in_i]'">
            <xsl:attribute name="ucum">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="unit">
                <xsl:value-of select="'m'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$val * 0.0254"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It is more flexible and uses a two-stage approach with the variable. 
The result is the same. I guess if you combine both, you'll find a good way fitting your needs.

Comment: Thanks. The second approach seems the best fit for my needs, as I do have a much more elaborate normalise template and I would also have to catch possible errors in the input, where incompatible measurement units are combined. I did not yet know about the sum( ) function - that does the trick, of course.

Comment: @4everJang In XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 there exists a cleaner and more efficient solution than doing multipass processing

Answer (score 0):

**No need for multi-pass processing -- XPath 2.0 is strong enough for this kind of problem:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="measurement[*]">
    <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">
      <xsl:value-of select=
                   "sum(measurement/(. * (if(@ucum eq '[ft_i]') then 0.3048 else 0.0254)))"/>
    </measurement>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is
        <measurement>
            <measurement unit="ft"
                ucum="[ft_i]">10</measurement>
            <measurement unit="in"
                ucum="[in_i]">2</measurement>
        </measurement>
        long
    </p>
</topic>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is
        <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">3.0988</measurement>
        long
    </p>
</topic>
```

---

**II. More Generic Solution**

One can produce a more generic solution, where the conversion is isolated into a separate XSLT `<xsl:function>`. Do note that **this solution will work even in cases when the conversion logic is so complex that it cannot be expressed in a single XPath expression** as was possible in the solution above. If the conversion is not just a simple multiplication, then it is not possible in general to present it as a table and use `xsl:key`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="my:f" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="measurement[*]">
    <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(measurement/f:convert(@ucum, .))"/>
    </measurement>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:convert">
    <xsl:param name="pFromUnit"/>
    <xsl:param name="pValue"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "$pValue * (if($pFromUnit eq '[ft_i]') then 0.3048 else 0.0254)"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct, wanted result is produced again**:

```
<topic>
    <p>This piece is
        <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">3.0988</measurement>
        long
    </p>
</topic>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have more than just 2 units, it would be convenient to store them in a variable and retrieve the corresponding conversion factor using a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="unit" match="unit" use="@name" />

<xsl:variable name="units">
    <unit name="ft" factor=".3048"/>
    <unit name="in" factor=".0254"/>
    <!-- add more units here ... -->
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="measurement[measurement]">
    <measurement ucum="m" unit="m">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(measurement/(. * key('unit', @unit, $units)/@factor))"/>    
    </measurement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxT